# Use condition to assign an element's value while declaring a subarray to be pushed into a result array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I need to put a condition when I create one element of my array

```
foreach ($score as $item):
     if ($item['subject_id'] == "3"){
         $file_data_array[] = array(
            "y" => $item['result'],
     ////Need condition here///////////////////////////////
            "color" => '#FFF'                
            );
      }
 endforeach;
```

So I need a condition like

```
if ($item['confirmed'] == 1) {  
    "color" => '#FFF'
} else {
    "color" => '#000'
}
```

So, since we cannot put an `if` inside an array, how can I do my condition?

Answer (score 5):

Try and use the [ternary if](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```php
foreach ($score as $item):
     if($item['subject_id'] == "3"){
         $file_data_array[] = array(
            "y" => $item['result'],
            "color" => ($item['confirmed'] == 1 ? '#FFF': '#000')
        );
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"color" => ($item['confirmed']==1 ? "#FFF" : "#000")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($score as $item):
 if($item['subject_id'] == "3"){
     if($item['confirmed'] == 1) {
         $color = '#FFF'; 
      } else {
         $color = '#000';
      }     
     $file_data_array[] = array(
        "y" => $item['result'],
        "color" => $color);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$login_detail=array(0=>array("sumit","8101"),1=>array("ashwani","9526"),2=>array("parmod","2592"),3=>array("jitendra","5792"),4=>array("umesh","5555"));
foreach($login_detail as $value)
{
    foreach($value as $value2 )
    {
        echo $value2." &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
$username=$_POST['txtusername'];
$password=$_POST['txtpassword'];
if($username==$login_detail && $password==$value)
{
     header("location: dashbord.php");
}
else
{
    header("location: loginexample.php?msg=user name or password is wrong");
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated